# Python selenium webdriver: only reading first reviewer information

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract all google reviews related to a restaurant. I wrote a python script that first loads all reviews into a web browser then I tried to read the information (such as the name of the reviewer) about the reviewers using for loop. My code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AOaemvJFjYToqQmQGGnZUovsXC1CObNK1g:1633336974491&q=10+famous+restaurants+in+Dunedin&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTsqaxrrDzAhXe4zgGHZPODcoQjGp6BAgKEGo&biw=1280&bih=557&dpr=2#lrd=0xa82eac0dc8bdbb4b:0x4fc9070ad0f2ac70,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5749134142351780976,l,CiAxMCBmYW1vdXMgcmVzdGF1cmFudHMgaW4gRHVuZWRpbiJDUjEvZ2VvL3R5cGUvZXN0YWJsaXNobWVudF9wb2kvcG9wdWxhcl93aXRoX3RvdXJpc3Rz2gENCgcI5Q8QChgFEgIIFkiDlJ7y7YCAgAhaMhAAEAEQAhgCGAQiIDEwIGZhbW91cyByZXN0YXVyYW50cyBpbiBkdW5lZGluKgQIAxACkgESaXRhbGlhbl9yZXN0YXVyYW50mgEkQ2hkRFNVaE5NRzluUzBWSlEwRm5TVU56ZW5WaFVsOUJSUkFCqgEMEAEqCCIEZm9vZCgA,y,2qOYUvKQ1C8;mv:[[-45.8349553,170.6616387],[-45.9156414,170.4803685]]'
driver.get(base_url)
 
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='P5Bobd']").text
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='T6pBCe']").text
overall_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//span[@class='Aq14fc']").text
total_reviews_text =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//div//div//span//span[@class='z5jxId']").text
num_reviews = int (total_reviews_text.split()[0])
all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))

total_review = len(all_reviews)

//   load all reviews into browser
while total_review < num_reviews:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class$="activityIndicator"]')))
        #all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gws-localreviews__google-review')
        all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
        total_review += 1
//read and display reviewer information
person_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']")
for person in person_info:
    name = person.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='TSUbDb']//a").text
    print(name)
```

Total number of reviewers were over 900. The problem with above code is that it only displays the first reviewer name for five times. Could anyone guide me where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with below code and confirm:

The xpath `//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']` for `person_info` is highlighting 3 diferent elements. And while finding an element within an element use a `.` in the xpath.

```
person_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='reviewSort']//div[contains(@class,'google-review')]")
for person in person_info:
    name = person.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div/div/a").text
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AOaemvJFjYToqQmQGGnZUovsXC1CObNK1g:1633336974491&q=10+famous+restaurants+in+Dunedin&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTsqaxrrDzAhXe4zgGHZPODcoQjGp6BAgKEGo&biw=1280&bih=557&dpr=2#lrd=0xa82eac0dc8bdbb4b:0x4fc9070ad0f2ac70,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5749134142351780976,l,CiAxMCBmYW1vdXMgcmVzdGF1cmFudHMgaW4gRHVuZWRpbiJDUjEvZ2VvL3R5cGUvZXN0YWJsaXNobWVudF9wb2kvcG9wdWxhcl93aXRoX3RvdXJpc3Rz2gENCgcI5Q8QChgFEgIIFkiDlJ7y7YCAgAhaMhAAEAEQAhgCGAQiIDEwIGZhbW91cyByZXN0YXVyYW50cyBpbiBkdW5lZGluKgQIAxACkgESaXRhbGlhbl9yZXN0YXVyYW50mgEkQ2hkRFNVaE5NRzluUzBWSlEwRm5TVU56ZW5WaFVsOUJSUkFCqgEMEAEqCCIEZm9vZCgA,y,2qOYUvKQ1C8;mv:[[-45.8349553,170.6616387],[-45.9156414,170.4803685]]'
driver.get(base_url)
 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/button/span").click() #clicks away the cookie

#div list of restaurants
div_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@jscontroller="AtSb"]')

for div in div_list:
    print(div)
    print(div.text)
exit()
```

maybe this helps, I modified it a bit, you maybe have to change some variables but you get the div.text which is (I believe) all the results on the first page